# Post.Cast<> no longer working after upgrade

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I have the following code (part of a class) which has not changed in years. I have recently moved to .net 4.7 from .net 4.5 and have upgraded from PostSharp 2 to Postsharp 5.0.34. The following code no longer executes and errors. I have been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days now but cannot see why this will no longer work? Can anyone shed any light on this please?

// Code Snippet

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class VimConnectionInfo : ConnectionInfoBase
{
    private const int HttpsPort = 443;

    public VimConnectionInfo()
    {
        this.SetDefaultValues();

        Post.Cast<VimConnectionInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged>(this).PropertyChanged += this.HandlePropertyChanged;
    }
```

From the snippet above the error occurs when the Post.Cast line is executed. The method, HandlePropertyChanged doesn't get executed due to the error. The error message is as follows

**Exception Message:** Unable to cast object of type 'Advantage.Reporter.VCenter.Infrastructure.Connection.VimConnectionInfo' to type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged'.

**Source:** PostSharp

**StackTrace:**    at PostSharp.Post.Cast[SourceType,TargetType](SourceType o)
   at Advantage.Reporter.VCenter.Infrastructure.Connection.VimConnectionInfo..ctor() in S:\VisualStudioProjects\Sonar.Portable\Advantage.Reporter.VCenter\Infrastructure\Connection\VimConnectionInfo.cs:line 33
   at Advantage.Reporter.VCenter.Infrastructure.Connection.VimConnectionAdapter.CreateConnectionInfo() in S:\VisualStudioProjects\Sonar.Portable\Advantage.Reporter.VCenter\Infrastructure\Connection\VimConnectionAdapter.cs:line 114
   at Advantage.Reporter.Core.Connections.ViewModels.ConnectionCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e) in S:\VisualStudioProjects\Sonar.Portable\Advantage.Reporter.Core.Wpf\Connections\ViewModels\ConnectionCollection.cs:line 38
   at System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.OnAddingNew(AddingNewEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.FireAddingNew()
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.AddNewCore()
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.System.ComponentModel.IBindingList.AddNew()
   at DevExpress.Data.Helpers.BaseDataControllerHelper.AddNewRow()
   at DevExpress.Data.BaseGridControllerEx.AddNewRow()

Comment: I assume the PostSharp assembly-rewriting step is failing. Have you tried looking in the build output for errors, or evidence that PostSharp isn't running?

Comment: My assumption would be that VomConnectionInfo needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm not too sure on what that attribute is though.

Comment: @KingOfArrows PostSharp rewrites your assembly after your code has been compiled, and one of the things it can do is to add an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your types. I assume that's what's happening here. The fact that it doesn't seem to be doing this implies that the rewriting step is failing in some way

Comment: I havent noticed anything in the Output of the build - the output can be viewed here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4vzwcjxjaytrun/output.txt?dl=0

Comment: @PaulDavey Now compare that to the build output where it worked, and see if you can spot any differences

Comment: Unforuntately I dont have a working build output

Comment: @PaulDavey You said it worked before you upgraded .NET and PostSharp. Go and check out that old commit, and build it

Comment: It's possible that PostSharp 2.0 was locally installed on your machine. With PostSharp 5.0, you should use NuGet packages. Just installing the Visual Studio extension will not make PostSharp transform your project.